# Detailed information about the Soyuz descent module connection box?

Tags: soyuz-spacecraft

Anyone have some detailed information about how all this connectors, located in the soyuz `descent module`?

Are they used only when they setup the Soyuz or they are also connected to the `equipment module`?

[image]

[image]

[Pictures from here](http://desertedplaces.blogspot.com/2012/08/a-russian-space-capsule-cemetery.html)

**Update 1** (TMA-19)

I get this picture from the module `TMA-19M` exposed in the Science museum in London

[image]
More info about the exposed module [here](https://collection.sciencemuseum.org.uk/objects/co8593265/soyuz-tma-19m-descent-module-s-p-korolev-rocket-and-space-public-corporation-energia?_ga=2.2522424.965800377.1560080779-1566817102.1559382857)

**Update 2** (MS-04)

From this [Soyuz MS-04 Construction, Testing and Integration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ftDskZgqbp8) video we can see this connection box multiple times

[image]

[Video here](https://youtu.be/ftDskZgqbp8?t=678)

[image]

[Video here](https://youtu.be/ftDskZgqbp8?t=1178)

[image]

[Video here](https://youtu.be/ftDskZgqbp8?t=1912)

**Update 3**

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-l7MM9yoxII) video which explains the process of reentry shows `in a rendered way` how the connections between de descent module and the others are disconected during the descending

[image]

Minute 9:45 of the [video](https://youtu.be/-l7MM9yoxII?t=585)

Here some basic details about the connection diagram between modules
[image]

Image from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_(spacecraft)#Soyuz_MS)

Comment: Welcome to *Space!*  Nice question.

Comment: Thanks, i see today one of this modules in the science museum of London and it was very impressive that amount of connectors.

Comment: [*Soyuz: A Universal Spacecraft*](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9781852336578) identifies it as "umbilical connector panel" but doesn't state whether or not it's an interface to the equipment module.

Comment: A quick browse through the Soyuz Crew Ops Manual yielded nothing either. Is this a standard module? It looks different from the one behind it.

Comment: I found more related information, looks like its connected during the flight so is not only for building or testing purposes